# Utility Maximization of a quasi-linear utility function

Tags: microeconomics, utility, consumer-theory

I am dealing with a quasi-linear utility function. For example
$U=(x_1x_2)^{0.5}+cx_3$ with constrain $w\ge x_1+2x_2+px_3$.By taking c, w and p as constant, I function that by using Lagrange multiplier method the F.O.C equations does not have a solution. I just don't know what's the problem. Thanks!

My attempt:

The budget constraint under this case is
\begin{equation}
    x_1+2x_2+p_3x_3\le w
\end{equation}
The corresponding Lagrangian (where $ \mu $ is the Lagrange multiplier) is
\begin{equation}
L=\sqrt{x_1x_2}+c x_3+\mu(w-x_1-2x_2-p_3x_3).
\end{equation}
Taking F.O.Cs, we have
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
    \frac{1}{2}x_2(x_1x_2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}-\mu=0 \\
\frac{1}{2}x_1(x_1x_2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}-2\mu=0 \\
c-p_3\mu=0 \\
w-x_1-2x_2-p_3x_3=0
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}

However, the above set of equations has no solution...

Comment: Hi! 1. What do you mean when you say this system of equation has no solution?

Comment: 2. Have you considered adding non-negativity constraints?

Comment: 3. Are you intent on using a Langrangian or would some other method suffice as well?

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem we want to solve:
\begin{eqnarray*} \max_{x_1,x_2,x_3} & x_1^{0.5}x_2^{0.5}+cx_3 \\ \text{s.t.} &x_1+2x_2+px_3\leq w \\ \text{and }& x_1\geq 0, x_2\geq 0, x_3\geq0\end{eqnarray*}
where $c>0, p>0, w>0$ are given.
It can be re-written as:
\begin{eqnarray*} \max_{0\leq x_3\leq w/p} \ \ \max_{x_1\geq 0,x_2\geq 0} & x_1^{0.5}x_2^{0.5}+cx_3 \\ \text{s.t.} & \ x_1+2x_2\leq w-px_3 \end{eqnarray*}
We can solve the problem in two steps. When we solve this:
\begin{eqnarray*} \max_{x_1\geq 0,x_2\geq 0} & x_1^{0.5}x_2^{0.5}+cx_3 \\ \text{s.t.} & \ x_1+2x_2\leq w-px_3 \end{eqnarray*}
we get:

$x_1=\dfrac{w-px_3}{2}$ and $x_2=\dfrac{w-px_3}{4}$. Therefore, we can write the second step of the problem as:
\begin{eqnarray*} \max_{0\leq x_3\leq w/p} & \dfrac{w-px_3+2\sqrt{2}cx_3}{2\sqrt{2}}\end{eqnarray*}

and the solution satisfy:
\begin{eqnarray*} x_3\in \begin{cases} \left\{\dfrac{w}{p}\right\} & \text{if } 2\sqrt{2}c > p \\ \left[0, \dfrac{w}{p}\right] & \text{if } 2\sqrt{2}c = p \\ \left\{0\right\} & \text{if } 2\sqrt{2}c < p \end{cases}\end{eqnarray*}

Given $x_3$ chosen as above, the corresponding values of $x_1, x_2$ are
\begin{eqnarray*} (x_1,x_2)= \begin{cases} (0,0) & \text{if } 2\sqrt{2}c > p \\ \left(\dfrac{w-px_3}{2},\dfrac{w-px_3}{4}\right) & \text{if } 2\sqrt{2}c = p \\ \left(\dfrac{w}{2},\dfrac{w}{4}\right) & \text{if } 2\sqrt{2}c < p \end{cases}\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks! This solution is really helpful. I am just wondering if there is any standard reasoning for solving it this way? Say like when facing a quasi-linear utility or some other weird things?

Comment: This is a standard reasoning which I use in my lectures for solving such problems. To learn the details, please visit: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLUJGfL_499TJ4xlOvpKeAqo4M5xYkq6wi&feature=shared